# How to update label (NSTextfield) without IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstextfield, awakefromnib

I’m trying to implement а simple mechanic: after draging а file, pass it’s name to lable. But I couldn’t understand how to do this. Here is my code:
H file:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
 @interface DropView : NSView <NSDraggingDestination> {}
 @property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *labelUrl; // <- label for file name
 @property NSString *urlStr;
 @end
```

M file:

```
 #import "DropView.h"
 @implementation DropView
 - (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType]];
      }
     return self;
 }
 - (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
     if ([sender draggingSourceOperationMask] & NSDragOperationCopy) {
         return NSDragOperationLink;
     }
     return NSDragOperationNone;
 }
 - (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
     return YES; 
 }
 - (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
     NSPasteboard *pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
     if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType] )
     {
         NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard:pboard];
         _urlStr = [[fileURL absoluteString] lastPathComponent]; // <- example "img.jpg"
         [self.labelUrl setStringValue:_urlStr]; // <- this is not work
     }
     return YES;
 }
 -(void)awakeFromNib {
     [_labelUrl setStringValue:@"no file name"]; 
 }
 @end
```

p.s.
I honestly searched for the answer here and in Google, but found none.

Comment: I am using the NSNotificationCenter, that tell me to update, if something change.

Comment: what is the value of _urlStr before you set it as label's string?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin It's contain filename from path/url, and before that it's Nil